# Nginx Gunicorn Flask SupervisorCtl - entered site is showing wrong site

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

I have a webserver that runs `Nginx` `Gunicorn` `Flask` `SupervisorCtl` however, after I added a supervisorctl config:

```
[program:websitecom]
command = gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8003
directory = /home/www/flask-deploy/websitecom
user = jd
autostart=true
autorestart=true
stderr_logfile=/var/log/standard_error_websitecom
stdout_logfile=/var/log=standard_out_websitecom
```

and nginx config:

```
server {
   server_name website.com;
   listen 80;
   location / {
       proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
       proxy_set_header Host $host;
       proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
   }
   location /static {
       alias  /home/www/flask-deploy/websitecom/;
   }
}
```

and flask config for `app.py` of:

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request
app = Flask(__name__)
app.secret_key = 'asecret'

@app.route("/")
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

The issue is, its showing a previously configured site hosted on the server, instead of the new domain.

Can someone please help?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check a few things when this happens.   Number 1, after updating your NGINX virtual host did you run?

```
>>> sudo service nginx reload 
>>> sudo service nginx restart
```

If this is not the issue the next thing you need to do is delete all the cache that could be telling your browser to point to the wrong domain for your IP address, multiple virtual hosts share the same IP.

You could also check to make sure your virtualhost is added to both your sites_enabled folder and your sites-available folder.

Finally, if that's not working than if NGINX is not configured correctly, the first correctly configured site will show up for your domain in question should another application be setup correctly.   For instance, if you have website1 working well... you add website2 and go to view in the url but instead of website2 showing up, you get website1 it could be that website2 just isn't configured correctly, which default to website1.

Comment: I tried your `code commented` area - that didnt work. I tried `deleting cache`,  `sites-enabled/sites-avail` both have config. I tried `nginx -t` and it said it was successful. any other thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that your Nginx server block is proxying to port 8000:

```
proxy_pass http://localhost:8000;
```

Whilst your Flask app is running on port 8003:

```
command = gunicorn app:app -b localhost:8003
```

I'd say you also have a Flask app running on port 8000 and this is what is showing?